# How to add attributes to Google Pubsub message using Google_Service_Pubsub_Topics_Resource (PHP)?

Tags: php, google-cloud-pubsub

I've got some legacy code, where I need to use the Google Pubsub old API Google_Service_Pubsub_Topics_Resource to publish a message. How do I add attributes to the message? I keep getting an error:

```
(publish) unknown parameter: 'myattr'
```

Here's the code:

```
$pubsubService = new Google_Service_Pubsub($client);
$req = new Google_Service_Pubsub_PublishRequest();
$req->setTopic("testtopic");
$msg = new Google_Service_Pubsub_PubsubMessage();
$msg->setData("....");
$req->setMessage($msg);
$opts = array(
    "myattr" => "test"
);
$ret = $pubsubService->topics->publish($req, $opts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-pub-sub) :

You need to put your attributes in an array with the key **attributes**.

So something like this :

```
$pubsubService->topics->publish($req, ['attributes' => ['myattr'=>'test']] );
```

Comment: tried that, got: unknown parameter: 'attributes'. Note I'm not using the new pubsub API but rather a legacy one as I mentioned above. Looking it up online is difficult, here's one instance: https://api.kdyby.org/class-Google_Service_Pubsub_Topics_Resource.html

Comment: Would the example 4 from : https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage work for you ?

Comment: The example is in Java - not PHP. While it appears this Java API version explicitly lets you specify attributes, I can't find how to do it in the PHP API version I'm using.